# print 0's before a variable

Tags: file, printing, octave, names

I know in c, c++, and all other kinds of programming code you can use the syntax "%4d" to print a total of 4 digits.  If the variable is only one digit, it will print three 0's and whatever your variable is, if your variable is 2 digits, two 0's and so on.  However in Octave it seems that it will print out spaces instead of 0's.  Is there a way to force it to print out zeros but keep the specified length of 4 integers?

This is for naming files that the program is outputting so the leading zero's are needed to help organize the data that is outputted.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect - you need `%04d` both in C and in Matlab/Octave.

Answer (score 0):

The place to look is the Matlab documentation: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html.

But the answer is something like:

```
sprintf('%04d', 42);  % Prints "0042"
```